# assigning running time

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

I'm trying to assign running times to loops of code to roughly get the upper asymptotic ($O$) running time.

```
while (j < n2) {                                   # executes n2-1 times
    int k = 0;                                         
    while ((k < n1) && (seq[k] < seq2[j])) {       # executes (n2-1)*n1times    
      k = k + 1;
      }
     // we want to insert seq2[j] at seq[k]
     // so we move seq[k] through seq[n1 - 1] to the right
     for (int i = n1; i > k; i = i - 1) {         # some n-k times
        seq[i] = seq[i - 1];
      }
     seq[k] = seq2[j];
     j = j + 1;
     n1 = n1 + 1;
}
```

I know this is bad but would this algorithm worst running time be something in O(n^2) because there is one main loop and then two separate nested loops inside the main loop?

Thanks

Comment: Seeing $n1$&$n2$, but not $n$, who is to tell? `I know this is bad` *what* do you know to be `bad`, and by what criterion?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the preceding code. If `seq` is initially empty the the run time of the outer loop is $O(n2)$ and the first nested loop is $O(k)$ and the second nested loop is $O(n1-k)$. The total running time would be $O(n2)*(O(k)+O(n1-k))$ which is $O(n^2)$.

However if seq has some initial elements, the worst case running time for the algorithm is $O(\infty)$. The problem is with the nested while loop `seq[k]>seq2[j]`. If any of the first `n` elements in `seq` are `>` `seq2[j]` the loop will not increment and run endlessly. Also you may run into array index out of range errors.

For example if `seq` = 2 , 1 , 0 and `seq2` = 1 , 2 , 3. Then `seq[0] > seq2[0]` would be equivalent to `2 > 1` which i s `false` and `k` would never increment.
The solution would be to use

```
n1 = sizeof(seq)/sizeof(seq[0])  # number of elements in seq
int k = 0;
for(; k < n1 ; k++){             # iterate over seq
    if( seq[k] >= seq2[j] )      # until an we find an element in seq >= seq2[j]
        break;
```

Comment: `first nested loop is O(k)` and `k` is initialised to zero - so that takes time independent on `n1`/`n2`? `If … the loop [control variable] will not increment` I can (sort of) see that `and run endlessly` - I think it just terminates. `may run into array index out of range` without additional knowledge about `n1` and `n2`: yes.